# Converting url to a unique integer

Tags: php, laravel

I am planning to fetch string objects from many rss sources. I run into an issue that there is not any id in many of them. Thus, I thought converting their url into a unique number would be a solution. Because if I keep them in string, it would be heavy task to query string values with mysql. What is the best way to take for that?  Is `md5()` good for that?

Comment: `md5` should be avoided at all costs...

Comment: What should I do instead; so that I can check if duplicate exists from db fast?

Comment: I'd say using a UUID or different hashing method, here's some food for thought: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

Comment: If I use UUID, I need to use varchar as mysql column, right? Then, isn't it going to be as slow as using string? Wouldn't I have performance issues to detect the duplicates if the database data gets big?

Comment: Why not an auto-incremented id in a database, or something?

Comment: Basically you'll want a hash method that is considered `dynamic perfect hashing`, which normally equates to being more memory intensive, but very useful for situations where fast queries, insertions, and deletions must be made on a large set of elements. Normally "static" hashing methods use two-tiered hash table schemes which is generally slower. It's unclear what you are doing with the hashes (are they just static references, or do they constantly get updated?).

Comment: The scenario is, I am fetching data from couple of RSS feeds, however only 1 item inside it gets replaced as new ones added. If I try to schedule a task to fetch all of them in every 5 min, then i will a unique id or something to not to have duplicate items in my database. And only unique thing in their array is the url, so I though converting url to integer and query it that way which would be faster than querying url string. I tried to ask, what is the best way to overcome this scenario?

Comment: Just use a fast hashing method as mentioned; you never said how many objects there are.

Comment: @senty all question details must be written into the question body.  Researchers should never have to read the comments to get the "full story".

Comment: I used this when i needed to do something similar. It also has some nice details around the reasons.. https://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2010/03/generating-unique-integer-ids-from-strings-in-mysql/